# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG misery and confusion

Tags: firefox, ssl

Hope this is the right StackExchange Q&A place...

I am trying to configure a VPS at Hostinger ... I am beginning to suspect it is too difficult for me and I may have to switch to a simpler "shared hosting" solution.

At the moment I am trying to understand in what way my setup at Hostinger is misconfigured.  Firefox displays the default page OK if (in the browser address box) I write "www.mikerodentstaging.xyz" or "mikerodentstaging.xyx" or even "http://www.mikerodentstaging.xyz"... but if I write "**https**://www.mikerodentstaging.xyz" I get the above failure message in Firefox.

In Chrome I get a similar thing, with a different message: "This site can’t provide a secure connection - [www.mikerodentstaging.xyz](http://www.mikerodentstaging.xyz) sent an invalid response." (only with the https address...)

The webchat guys at Hostinger are really very helpful... but try as they might they can't help with this. I think it's something to do with SSL and "certificates" and "keys" ... but other than that I'm completely at a loss as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not the right site. Try [su] or ask in [meta.se] for a site recommendation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined in [help/on-topic].